# Lighting:tabset rendering tabs in "more" drop down when tabs are populated dynamically even though it has enough space to display all tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, dynamic, lightning-tab

My expected result should be, all tabs display in one line with out "more" option by using dynamic code.

When i tried dynamic code, Tabset displays only 3 names and rest of them in more option as show below even though it has enough space to display all values.
[image]

Below is the code. 
===DYNAMIC CODE====

```
<lightning:tabset>
   <!-- Dynamic, but displays on 3 tabs and more option for other tabs -->
         <aura:iteration items="{!v.systemNames}" var="sys">
               <lightning:tab label="{!sys}" id="{!sys}"/>
          </aura:iteration>    
</lighitng:tabset>
```

When i hard code the same list in component itself, all of them are displaying as expected.
[image]

=======HARDCODED=======

```
<lightning:tabset>
     <!-- Hard coded the names to display all of them in one set -->
      <lightning:tab label="AMBPL" id="AMBPL"/>
       <lightning:tab label="AUGPL" id="AUGPL"/>
       <lightning:tab label="CLVNR" id="CLVNR"/>
       <lightning:tab label="DELTA" id="DELTA">
                 ....
                 ....
</lightning:tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it behaves better if all possible tabs are available at init time. Try wrapping the whole thing inside an `aura:if` that doesn't render until the list is fully available.

Comment: I tried it too. But no luck.   isLoaded is made to be true only after full list is available.

 
 **<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoaded}">**
              Iteration Logic
  </aura:if>